# upgrade from 3.2.2 to 3.2.8 breaks jquery-tooltip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-plugins, jquery-tooltip

I just upgraded my app from 3.2.2 to 3.2.8.

I use jquery-tooltip.

Once I upgraded,  the tooltip changed behavior.  Prior to the upgrade,  the tooltip would popup positioned relative the element that contains a title,  invoked like:

```
$("[title]").tooltip();
```

After the upgrade,  the tooltip is now different.  I never looked at the generated HTML when it WAS working correctly,  but now,  when I call tooltip on a titled element,  it creates a DIV for the tooltip at the end of my HTML,  so the tooltip appears at the bottom of my page.

I noticed that jquery-ui just got upgraded to 2.0.0,  so I'm assuming that when I do this in  my app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-tooltip.min
```

I'm now grabbing the newer version,  which is no longer compatible with jquery-tooltip.

Anybody know for sure?

Any quick fix?

I'm not married to jquery-tooltip,  anybody have a proven jquery tooltip approach for rails 3.2.8?  (jquery-ui tooltip due in upcoming 1.9 release?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I had copies of the jquery.ui javascript files in app/assets/javascripts

They should of been removed as soon as I added:

```
//= require jquery_ui
```

to my app/assets/javascripts/application.js manifest.

When I upgraded to 2.3.8 it introduced dependencies on jquery-ui later than the version I had copied long ago.

Simply removing them fixed my problem